# Kivy - Switch between TabbedPanelItems in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a small problem with switching between TabbedPanelItems in code.

### Problem

I have several tabs where one is used to set some parameters and select a file to load. These parameters affect how the other tabs present some data to the user. Because of this, I want to check the settings (e.g. check if a file is selected) before the user switches tabs.
My current solution is to let the user switch tabs and in case of a problem, I notify the user with a popup and switch back to the settings tab. However, when switching back, the content of the TabbedPanelItem is not the one related to the settings tab.

Here is a snippet my current code:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<MyScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: '6dp'

    tabbed_panel: TP_inspect_screen
    settings_tab: TPI_settings_tab

    TabbedPanel:
        id: TP_inspect_screen
        default_tab: TPI_settings_tab
        on_current_tab: root.onTabChange(self.current_tab)
        TabbedPanelItem:
            id: TPI_settings_tab
            text: 'Settings'
            Label:
                text: 'Settings'

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Table'
            Button:
                text: 'HELLO'

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Plot'
```

and

```
class MyScreen(BoxLayout):
    
    settings_tab = ObjectProperty(None)
    tabbed_panel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def onTabChange(self, tab):

        if tab.text == 'Table':
            self.tabbed_panel.switch_to(self.tabbed_panel.default_tab)
            #self.tabbed_panel.switch_to(self.settings_tab)
```

In the example above, I've omitted the mentioned checks.
What happens is that when I switch (by clicking) to the 'Plot' tab, I see an empty screen and when I switch back to the 'Settings' tab, I see the Label as expected.
When I try switching to the 'Table' tab, I get immediately returned to the 'Settings' tab but the content of the tab is the Button of the 'Table' tab:

[image]

Best, Julz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it switched to the default tab too fast.

## Solution

Use Kivy Clock [`schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) function to switch to the default tab. In the snippets, we are using 0.1 seconds to show the switching in slow motion. You can change it to 0 seconds.

## Snippets - py

```
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyScreen(BoxLayout):

    settings_tab = ObjectProperty(None)
    tabbed_panel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def onTabChange(self, tab):
        if tab.text == 'Table':
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.tabbed_panel.switch_to(self.tabbed_panel.default_tab), 0.1)
```